# Struggling to grant remote HTTP access on a proxy server

Tags: proxy, squid

I've been desperately trying to setup squid on a virtual machine (hosted by digital ocean) for the past day or so. I've set up the machine which has Ubuntu operating system, installed Squid and modified the config as I'm trying to grant access to my home PC (as obviously they aren't on the same LAN net work). I thought this was done by making the edits I've shown below,

```
acl myips src MYPUBLICIP
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow myips
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow manager myips
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access allow purge myips
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
```

from my limited understanding I've allowed access to the top IP - should I be using my Laptops IPv4 address here (10.213.111.121)?

If someone could talk me through this I was be SO grateful as I'm really not getting anywhere...

Thanks!

Comment: If they aren't on the same LAN how are you routing between the two? 10.x.x.x is private address space; so unless you have some routing this won't work. The src IP will have to be the IP presented by your requesting machine to the local machine (ie. the IP on its external interface)

Comment: So do you mean I should be using the ip that shows publicly (i.e. If I go on to a site search as 'whatismyip' and use this instead? Sorry, I really do have a limited amount of knowledge when it comes to this... to answer re: 
If they aren't on the same LAN how are you routing between the two? - I'm not, as I'm not sure how? (is this what people refer to as port forwarding?)

Comment: Yes; exactly. Think about what IP is being presented to the squid box.

Comment: Right, I went on to 'whatismyip' and tried to use the public address also but this didn't work either. I thought maybe I was still doing something wrong with the config. Do I need to give access to the public address and also the Ipv4 address so it checks for access to my public address then checks the private address of my laptop?